# Combining Task and IAsyncResult

Tags: c#, wcf, async-await, task

In WCF by implementing `IOperationInvoker` I'm trying to test whether the caller is authorized or not before calling the actual method. But I want to do it in async way because my methods are all async ones.
The problem is I don't know how to combine the `Task` and `IAsyncResult` together.
In `InvokeBegin`, first I want to check for authorization and then return the original method's call.
My `AauthorizeAsync` method is defined like this:

```
private static async Task<bool> AauthorizeAsync(string[] claims)
```

I did something like this but on exception the execution doesn't continue, seems the calling thread doesn't receive any feedback and stays orphaned.

```
public IAsyncResult InvokeBegin(object instance, object[] inputs, AsyncCallback callback, object state)
{
    return AauthorizeAsync(_claims)
        .ContinueWith(task =>
                      {
                          var authorized = task.Result;

                          if (!authorized)
                          {
                              throw new WebFaultException(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
                          }

                          return _defaultInvoker.InvokeBegin(instance, inputs, callback, state);
                      });
}
```

The working code is this but it's synced. How can I convert it to fully async?

```
public IAsyncResult InvokeBegin(object instance, object[] inputs, AsyncCallback callback, object state)
{
    var authorized = AauthorizeAsync(_claims).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

    if (!authorized)
    {
        throw new WebFaultException(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
    }

    return _defaultInvoker.InvokeBegin(instance, inputs, callback, state);
}

public object InvokeEnd(object instance, out object[] outputs, IAsyncResult result)
{
    return _defaultInvoker.InvokeEnd(instance, out outputs, result);
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `IAsyncResult` to begin with? Why not generate task based async methods in WCF?

Comment: It's the requirement of WCF's IOperationInvoker, somewhat old. :)

Comment: @SametSorgut did you find a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use an async `IOperationInvoker`. You can use a sync one and still have an async action. This is probably the easiest course of action.

If you want an async one, you need to make use of the `IAsyncResult` returned from `_defaultInvoker.InvokeBegin(instance, inputs, callback, state);`. Right now, this value is not ever looked at again.

Use `Task.FromAsync` to make a task from it. Then, you can return that task and call `Unwrap`. It's even easier if you use `await`. `ContinueWith` should be a code smell.

```
var authorized = await AauthorizeAsync(_claims);

if (!authorized)
{
    throw new WebFaultException(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
}

await Task.FromAsync(..., _defaultInvoker.InvokeBegin(instance, inputs, callback, state), ...);
```

This must be in a new `async` method. The resulting task can then act as an `IAsyncResult` that encompasses everything.

Comment: Task.Factory.FromAsync() need both InvokeBegin and InvokeEnd mothods specified. I can't specify the InvokeEnd there.It's already called by the caller object.

Comment: It would be `_defaultInvoker.InvokeEnd` which you can call. Your caller does not need to know about `_defaultInvoker` in any way. You can encapsulate that call.